# How to solve this recurrence of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_n=n\cdot x_{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x_{n-2}$

Thanks to Barry Cipra's suggestion, now I have obtained the solution for $x_n$:

$x_n=\frac{n!}{\sqrt{3}}((\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2})^n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:  Let $u_n=x_n/n!$.  Find (and solve) a recurrence relation for $u_n$.

Comment: Brilliant! It is much simplified. Then it is deduced to solve this problem:  $u_1=1$, $u_2=1$, $u_n=u_{n-1}+\frac{u_{n-2}}{2}$. 

But I still can not find a close form solution for it.

Comment: Ok, I find a solution for $u_n=u_{n-1}+\frac{u_{n-2}}{2}$ in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#General_methods

Comment: But what if $nx_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$

Comment: @Rejo_Slash, that's a completely different question.  If you post it as such, you will probably get an answer.

Comment: I posted it..But couldnt end up in a solution...I just saw your methods..Just checking whether you know how to deal it..Please go through the [link of my post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881732/recurrence-solution-of-simple-recurrence)!