# Solving the recursion $F(n)=K_0F(n-1)/(n-1)+K_1F(n-2)/(n-2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Please help me in solving the recursion   $F(n)=K_0\frac{F(n-1)}{n-1}+K_1\frac{F(n-2)}{n-2}$, preferably using power series for the values of $F(n)$ in terms of $n$. Here $K_1$ and $K_2$  are constants. We are given  $F(0)=0,F(1)=3,F(2)=3/2$. Any methods of solution is welcome, even partial answers. We can discuss further. Thanks for taking time to read my question.

Comment: $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=3$. Edited

Comment: With the exception of the scalar boundary conditions, this question is a duplicate of your [previous one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881732) under the identification $F(n)=n f(n)$.

Comment: yes there is similarity. I decided to post a simpler version,as the matrix case may make others confused

Comment: And aslo there I said matrices are skew symmetric etc.. I have plans to extent it. So I avoided that here for a general one..Please dont get confused..