# Fibonaaci Recurrence

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

This is an interesting question where we are trying to solve another recursion which has same tree structure as the given recursion  and also has term similarities

**Given Data in question**

1. $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, where $F_1=F_2=1$, we have $F_n= \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^n-(1-\sqrt{5})^n}{2^n\sqrt{5}}$ and generating function $g(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_nx^n=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$
2. More details of Fibonacci recursion and properties can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html)! .

**Question**

Can we find solution for a)$Q_n$(interms of n)  b) $ g(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Q_nx^n $ for the given recursion below   **$nQ_n=Q_{n-1}+Q_{n-2}\tag 3$**
$Q_1=Q_2=1$,by using the above results, given the fact that both follows same recursion tree  (in structure) even though results are different? if so please answer
[image]

NB :: This is not a home work problem. Logic is simple,the varying n will make it tough. And no  prof will give it as home work. I am trying this for weeks/months.. It is not simple. Attempt on a similar problem by me  can be found   [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881732/recurrence-solution-of-simple-recurrence)

NB :: **I know a method of using ODE. But I am trying to solve it with out ODE so that I can extent this to higher dimension like matrices in similar structure questions. Please avoid ODE solution**

Comment: Please avoid being judgmental with out reading the question. Havent you seen the varying n there ?Which professor will give this question as home work.. I am out of college for long.. This is a simplified version of the problem I am trying to solve for months..You gave negative for this? What is wrong with you.. See a different version of it I tried [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881732/recurrence-solution-of-simple-recurrence).Since I didnt get answer, I thought to try in different persepctive.. After thinking  of this I posted it.now got a reply "free home work service" &^#$%

Comment: @Rejo_Slash Some people (like me) like to see what the purpose of a question is so that we don't end up doing someone else's homework or whatever.  "I'm out of college and have been working on this for months" is a great addition to a question in my opinion and would help you if you state in the question.

Comment: Thanks DanielV for the suggestion.. Got really itched by seeing that  quote " free homework service"..

Comment: I don't even understand what the question is. Do you want a formula for $Q_n$ in the same way as you have it for $F_n$?

Comment: @5xum  Yes.. I tried all normal cases I know..So thought to extract something from similar recursion $F_n$

Comment: Why the fact that you want to consider matrix cases should prevent you to use ODE techniques? These extend pretty well to matrix settings...

Comment: Yes It will prevent. Reason is,the non commutativity in matrices..It will happen when you try to solve it by using integrating factors.. It wont be flexible as normal case..

Comment: No it does not, one just has to be careful to not use commutativity since it is illegal for matrices, but many things work fine. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 1):

g'(x) = 1 + 2x + (1+x)g(x)

I am not giving the derivation in case this is a homework question, but it should be easy to work out.

Once you get this, you can solve this integral using standard techniques. Try wolfram:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%27%28x%29+%3D+1+%2B+2x+%2B+%281%2Bx%29g%28x%29

Now to get $Q_n$ compare coefficients of x.

Comment: I know the derivation of this..  I needed one with out ODE. Reason is I have to extent it to a similar problem with matrices. I forgot to mention that .. I will edit now

Comment: Given that no multiplication of elements from $Q_{n-1}$ and $Q_{n-2}$ is going on, even if you use matrices won't it boil down to a recurrence of this form for each element?

Comment: I meant an extented version of the same structure.. if $nQ_n=Q_{n-1}K_1+Q_{n-2}K_2$ where $K_1,K_2  $,are matrices then we cant extent it as  we cant   make sure  commutative properties..

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the $Q_n$ for $n=0\ldots 11$ gives,

$n!Q_n = A_n$ with $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N_0} = \{1,1,2,4,10,26,76,232,764,2620,9496,35696,\ldots\}$

at least the comments on

http://www.oeis.org

should give you some hints for the respective matching sequences.

Comment: You are implying if we find this series in n we can come to the solution? But wouldn't that be empirical..?

Comment: Series what series? I hope you mean sequence. The first thing one should do, if one encounters an unknown sequence, is to calculate some elements of the sequence and consult www.oeis.org, which is a great source of background information. The next thing is to see, if there are some closed formulae for your sequence, which are also often provided on www.oeis.org. You haven't even provided some information, in what situation your sequence appeared and what kind of calculations you had tried before your post. I'm implying nothing here. But for a proof one should use all available information.

Comment: no no .please inform me what information you are missing..

Comment: most of the time you only need first two initial values, if you have a given recurrence. Then we can manipulate on it by power series etc.. I had given link of my previous post related to this where I tried thanks

Comment: I simply provided some information for others, who would like to work on this problem further. You haven't even specified what kind of form you are expecting for your question a).

Comment: I had specified ..I have updated now for more specifically..Thanks

Comment: So $Q_n = (Q_{n-1} + Q_{n-2})/n$ is an expression in $n$, which can be shown using complete induction, and a) is solved?

Comment: Oh no no... What I meant was to get an expression with out Qs..fully on n.. means $Q(n)=U(n)$.. where $U(n)$ doest not contain any Q terms..thanks andre

Comment: try to proof the hermite polynomial hint on www.oeis.org.